# Problem with WFS various versions in OpenLayers

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wfs-t

I'm developing an application using [OpenLayers-3.8.2](http://openlayers.org) and geoserver-2.7.2. I defined a wfs layer as follow:

```
var url = "http://localhost:8084/geoserver/wfs?&service=WFS&" +
           "version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=Calk:Point&" + 
           "outputFormate=application/json";

var format = new ol.format.WFS();
source = new ol.source.Vector({
    url: 'proxy.cgi?url=' + encodeURIComponent(u),
    format: format
});

layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    title: 'Iran bound',
    source: source
});
map.addLayer(layer);
```

The above code makes a WFS version **1.1.0** request. With this version it works fine, but when I change it to **1.0.0** or **2.0.0** it does not work. Server response for various versions are as follows:

**Version: 1.0.0**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wfs:FeatureCollection xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" 
                xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:Calk="http://itsme.calk.ir" 
                xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://localhost:8084/geoserver/schemas/wfs/1.0.0/WFS-basic.xsd 
                http://itsme.calk.ir http://localhost:8084/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&amp;version=1.0.0&amp;request=DescribeFeatureType&amp;typeName=Calk%3APoint">
    <gml:boundedBy>
        <gml:Box srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326">
            <gml:coordinates xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">27.195,28.9653 53.4167,60.8482</gml:coordinates>
        </gml:Box>
    </gml:boundedBy>
    <gml:featureMember>
        <Calk:Point fid="Point.1">
            <gml:boundedBy>
                <gml:Box srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326">
                    <gml:coordinates xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">28.4101,41.5723 28.4101,41.5723</gml:coordinates>
                </gml:Box>
            </gml:boundedBy>
            <Calk:the_geom>
                <gml:Point srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326">
                    <gml:coordinates xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">28.4101,41.5723</gml:coordinates>
                </gml:Point>
            </Calk:the_geom>
            <Calk:AREA>0.0</Calk:AREA>
            <Calk:PERIMETER>0.0</Calk:PERIMETER>
            <Calk:IR_CEN_>1</Calk:IR_CEN_>
            <Calk:IR_CEN_ID>9</Calk:IR_CEN_ID>
            <Calk:X_COORD>45.08176</Calk:X_COORD>
            <Calk:Y_COORD>37.57299</Calk:Y_COORD>
            <Calk:NAME>ORUMIEH-iran</Calk:NAME>
        </Calk:Point>
    </gml:featureMember>
    ...
</wfs:FeatureCollection>
```

**Version 1.1.0**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wfs:FeatureCollection xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:Calk="http://itsme.calk.ir" 
                       xmlns:world="http://itsme.world.ir" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" 
                       xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:iran="http://itsme.iran.ir" 
                       xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows" 
                       xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                       numberOfFeatures="25" timeStamp="2015-08-08T12:02:52.752Z" 
                       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs 
                        http://localhost:8084/geoserver/schemas/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd 
                        http://itsme.calk.ir http://localhost:8084/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&amp;version=1.1.0&amp;request=DescribeFeatureType&amp;typeName=Calk%3APoint">
    <gml:boundedBy>
        <gml:Envelope srsDimension="2" srsName="urn:x-ogc:def:crs:EPSG:4326">
            <gml:lowerCorner>28.96533966064453 27.195</gml:lowerCorner>
            <gml:upperCorner>60.8482 53.41667175292969</gml:upperCorner>
        </gml:Envelope>
    </gml:boundedBy>
    <gml:featureMembers>
        <Calk:Point gml:id="Point.1">
            <gml:boundedBy>
                <gml:Envelope srsName="urn:x-ogc:def:crs:EPSG:4326" srsDimension="2">
                    <gml:lowerCorner>41.5723 28.4101</gml:lowerCorner>
                    <gml:upperCorner>41.5723 28.4101</gml:upperCorner>
                </gml:Envelope>
            </gml:boundedBy>
            <Calk:the_geom>
                <gml:Point srsName="urn:x-ogc:def:crs:EPSG:4326" srsDimension="2">
                    <gml:pos>41.5723 28.4101</gml:pos>
                </gml:Point>
            </Calk:the_geom>
            <Calk:AREA>0.0</Calk:AREA>
            <Calk:PERIMETER>0.0</Calk:PERIMETER>
            <Calk:IR_CEN_>1</Calk:IR_CEN_>
            <Calk:IR_CEN_ID>9</Calk:IR_CEN_ID>
            <Calk:X_COORD>45.08176</Calk:X_COORD>
            <Calk:Y_COORD>37.57299</Calk:Y_COORD>
            <Calk:NAME>ORUMIEH-iran</Calk:NAME>
        </Calk:Point>
        ...
    </gml:featureMembers>
</wfs:FeatureCollection>
```

**Version 2.0.0**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wfs:FeatureCollection xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:Calk="http://itsme.calk.ir" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0" 
    xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    numberMatched="25" numberReturned="25" timeStamp="2015-08-08T12:03:28.744Z" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0 
        http://localhost:8084/geoserver/schemas/wfs/2.0/wfs.xsd 
        http://itsme.calk.ir http://localhost:8084/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&amp;version=2.0.0&amp;request=DescribeFeatureType&amp;typeName=Calk%3APoint 
        http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2 http://localhost:8084/geoserver/schemas/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd">
    <wfs:boundedBy>
        <gml:Envelope>
            <gml:lowerCorner>28.96533966064453 27.195</gml:lowerCorner>
            <gml:upperCorner>60.8482 53.41667175292969</gml:upperCorner>
        </gml:Envelope>
    </wfs:boundedBy>
    <wfs:member>
        <Calk:Point gml:id="Point.1">
            <gml:boundedBy>
                <gml:Envelope srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326" srsDimension="2">
                    <gml:lowerCorner>41.572266 28.410145</gml:lowerCorner>
                    <gml:upperCorner>41.572266 28.410145</gml:upperCorner>
                </gml:Envelope>
            </gml:boundedBy>
            <Calk:the_geom>
                <gml:Point srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326" srsDimension="2">
                    <gml:pos>41.572266 28.410145</gml:pos>
                </gml:Point>
            </Calk:the_geom>
            <Calk:AREA>0.0</Calk:AREA>
            <Calk:PERIMETER>0.0</Calk:PERIMETER>
            <Calk:IR_CEN_>1</Calk:IR_CEN_>
            <Calk:IR_CEN_ID>9</Calk:IR_CEN_ID>
            <Calk:X_COORD>45.08176</Calk:X_COORD>
            <Calk:Y_COORD>37.57299</Calk:Y_COORD>
            <Calk:NAME>ORUMIEH-iran</Calk:NAME>
        </Calk:Point>
        ...
    </wfs:member>
</wfs:FeatureCollection>
```

**Where is the problem**?

**Is it [OpenLayers](http://geoserver.org) bug**?

**How do I fix it**?

A another thing is that when I use wfs in version **1.1.0** and I modify some features, I save layer according to [this tutorial](http://wordpress-dbauszus.rhcloud.com/?p=71), And **in geoserver the points coordinates are displaced** (*mypoint.x in client side save as y in server side and vice versa*). But when I create a new feature, ***It save correctly***.
It's astounding and I'm confused. **What do I do**?

Comment: It seems you get a good response each time what is your question?

Comment: But in version 1.0.0 and 2.0.0 does not show anything.

Comment: note you have spelt    "outputFormate=application/json"; wrong which is why you get GML back

Comment: Not because it is not

Comment: You can use WFS 1.0.0 by defining a GML2 parser in the `ol.format.WFS` instance. `var format = new ol.format.WFS({gmlFormat: new ol.format.GML2()});` You can't use WFS 2.0.0 though.

Answer (score 2):

OL3.8.2 only supports WFS 1.1.0. See docs:

> ol.format.WFS
>   Feature format for reading and writing data in the WFS format. By default, supports WFS version 1.1.0. You can pass a GML format as option if you want to read a WFS that contains GML2 (WFS 1.0.0). Also see ol.format.GMLBase which is used by this format.